# Why the result is different in combinatory exercise?

Tags: combinatorics

I have a statement that says:

> In a bingo, each card can be used for two games, in how many ways Can
>   you distribute the 2 biggest prizes, if there are 10 cards in total?

My development was:

i have 2 prizes, 10 cards and each card can be used for two games.

When the first prize is won, i have $\frac{(n + r - 1) !}{(n - 1)! * r !} = \frac{(10 + 1 - 1) !}{(10 - 1)! * 1 !}$ = $\frac{10!}{9!} = 10$ possible winners, and when the second prize is won, i have $10$ too.

And according to the additive principle, is $20$, since the games do not happen simultaneous.

But my problem, is that the correct answer must be $100$, so I want to know, what have I done wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake is in using the additive principle. We use the additive principle when we count disjoint possibilities, so you're saying there are $10$ ways for someone to get the first prize, and $10$ says for someone to get the second prize, and $20$ total ways for a single person to get a single  prize. The results you're looking for are who gets the first prize **and** who gets the second prize, so each possibility distributes both prizes. Then you have to use the multiplicative principle, and get $10*10=100$ possibilities.

Think of it like clothing- if you have $3$ shirts and $4$ pairs of pants, taking the sum would count ways of picking a single shirt, or picking a single pair of pants. But if you want to count number of ways to pick a complete outfit, both shirt and pants, you have to take the product.

Answer (score 1):

You have mistaken what the results are that you are adding.

The first set of results:

$\{\text{Card 1 wins the first game},\text{Card 2 wins the first game},\text{Card 3 wins the first game},\dots,\text{Card 10 wins the first game}\}$

The second set of results:

$\{\text{Card 1 wins the second game},\text{Card 2 wins the second game},\text{Card 3 wins the second game},\dots,\text{Card 10 wins the second game}\}$

Although the *time* at which the games occur is not "simultaneous" the *results* are both able to happen.  It is possible for card1 to both win the first game and win the second game for example.

Compare this to a correct time at which you add such as $\{\text{Card 1 wins the first game},\text{Card 3 wins the first game},\text{Card 5 wins the first game},\text{Card 7 wins the first game},\text{Card 9 wins the first game}\}$ $\{\text{Card 2 wins the first game},\text{Card 4 wins the first game},\text{Card 6 wins the first game},\text{Card 8 wins the first game},\text{Card 10 wins the first game}\}$

giving $5+5$ ways in which the first game could be won since it is (presumably) impossible for both Card1 *and* Card2 to both win the first game as each game (presumably) only has one winner.

---

That being said, if all you care about is who received the prizes, but you don't care about what times it occurred at (*e.g. if the prize for game1 is the same as the prize for game2*) then there would have been $\binom{10}{2}+10=55$ possible results, not $100$.